# Collection view is crashing for some reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

```
    //collection view
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

 }



- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)tcollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}


// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}
```

crash on :

```
 -[NSISUnrestrictedVariable collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fce804111b0
```

What is that ?
(the collection view is inside a view controller,tand he is inside a scrollview)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `UICollectionView` has been deallocated from memory but you are still trying to access it.

Enable `NSZombies` and you'll see where you make the call to the deallocated memory and fix the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution . As mentioned here, the collection view is deallocated from memory.

Reason is because that view controller that holds it, is inside a scrollview, and i didn't create it a property as strong to retain it , so :

```
//the view controller that holds the collection

    @property(nonatomic,strong) BlisterView *blister;
```

solves the problem.